# Cardinality of $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, cardinals, real-numbers

As far as I remember the closed set $[0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$ contains every real number being that the cardinality of $[0,1]$ is the same of $\mathbb{R}$. 
If so can someone post an explicit biijection and in such case what is the antiimage of $\pi$ and $e$?

Comment: Can you find a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $[0,1]$? If does, you can find  the bijection you want because $f(x) = \cot \pi x/2$ is a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Such bijection does not exist. ( I think ) But the bijection you are looking for exists between $(0,1)$ and $R$.

Comment: The problem is that a bijection $[0, 1] \rightarrow {\bf R}$, while it exists, cannot be continuous.  (So, its explicit definition may not be pretty.)  But, a bijection  $(0, 1) \rightarrow {\bf R}$ can be.

Comment: "contains every real number." Nope. Two sets having the same cardinality is not the same as two sets having the same elements.

Comment: @Sina That is incorrect. See my answer.

Comment: That raises another question: Is it possible to have a continuous map from $\mathbb{R}$ onto $[0,1]$?

Comment: @Cronus Sure - take $f(x)=x$ if $x\in [0,1]$, $f(x)=0$ if $x<0$, and $f(x)=1$ if $x>1$. On the other hand, no continuous map can go from $[0, 1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and be onto - the continuous image of a compact set is always compact.

Comment: @Noah Sorry, I meant a continuous bijection. Maybe that's not possible because a continuous injective map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is monotonous? I'm a bit rusty.

Comment: @Cronus Then that is impossible. Proof: suppose $f$ were a continuous bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $[0, 1]$. Let $a=f^{-1}(0)$, $b=f^{-1}(1)$, and suppose WLOG that $a<b$. Let $c$ be some real *not* in $(a, b)$, and let $f(c)=y$. Since $0<y<1$ (why?), by the intermediate value theorem there is some $d\in (a, b)$ such that $f(d)=y$. But then $f(c)=f(d)$, but $c\not=d$ - so $f$ is not injective. Contradiction.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Good. Pretty similar to what I have in mind.

Answer (score 5):

The [**Cantor-Bernstein Theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) shows - explicitly! - that if I have injections from $A$ to $B$ and from $B$ to $A$, then there is a bijection from $A$ to $B$. By "explicitly," I mean that the proof actually constructs a bijection from the two injections given.

To apply this here, note that $[0, 1]$ clearly injects into $\mathbb{R}$, being a subset of it; in the other direction, consider the map $x\mapsto {2(\arctan(x)+{\pi\over 2})\over\pi}.$ This map injects $\mathbb{R}$ into $[0, 1]$ (with image $(0, 1)$).

Note, however, that there is no *continuous* bijection between $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb{R}$; so any bijection is going to be a bit messy.

---

Here's an outline of a specific example.

- First, let $f$ be the map given above which injects $\mathbb{R}$ into $[0, 1]$. Now, this fails to be a bijection because it missed two points . . .
- So let's fix it! Pick a countable subset $A$ of $(0, 1)$ - e.g. $\mathbb{Q}\cap (0, 1)$. Write this subset as $A=\{a_1, a_2, a_3, . . .\}$.
- Now, consider the map $g$ sending $a_1$ to $0$, $a_2$ to $1$, and $a_{i+2}$ to $a_i$. (Think [Hilbert's hotel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel).)
- The map $g\circ f$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $[0, 1]$.

You asked about what happens to specific real numbers under such a bijection. Well, obviously that depends on the bijection used - there are lots of bijections from $\mathbb{R}$ to $[0, 1]$, and we can arrange for $e$ to go to whatever real number we want it to!

In the example I've given here, the choice you have is basically what countable set you pick, and how you enumerate it. For example, since $f(e)$ is irrational, in the specific case above $g$ wouldn't move $f(e)$, so $g\circ f(e)=f(e)={2(\arctan(e)+{\pi\over 2})\over\pi}$. Similarly with $f(\pi)$.

Answer (score 2):

A bijection from $[0,1]$ to $(0,1)$, is the following $f(0)=1/2$, $f(1)=1/4$, for $n\geq 1$, $f(1/2^n)=1/2^{n+2}$ and $f(x)=x$ otherwise.
A bijection from $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is $g(x)=\tan(\pi(x-1/2))$.
Hence a bijection from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$, if $h:=g\circ f$.
Therefore $h^{-1}(e)=g^{-1}(e)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\arctan(e)}{\pi}$.